# Wordpress custom post type loop pagination always go to homepage

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages, wordpress-shortcode

I have a custom post type that I want to loop with pagination. However it display correctly but whenever you click the pagination (1,2,3,4 next and prev) it always goes to the homepage. I use a shortcode to display on the page. Thanks in advance!

---

ob_start();
global $post;

```
    $paged = ( get_query_var('paged') ) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;

    $args = array (
        'post_type'     => 'ebooks-guides',
        'posts_per_page' => 4,
        'orderby'=> 'title',
        'order' => 'ASC',
        'paged' => $paged,
    
    );
    ?>
    <?php $the_query = new WP_Query( $args ); ?>
    <?php if (  $the_query->have_posts() )  : ?>
        <div class="ebooks-guides-container">
            <?php while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post();?>
                <div class="ebooks-guides">
                    <figure>
                        <?php the_post_thumbnail('single-post-thumbnail'); ?>
                    </figure>
                    <div class="ebooks-guides-description">
                        <h2><?php echo get_the_title(); ?></h2>
                        <?php the_content(); ?>
                        <?php
                            $link = get_field('webinar_link');
                            if( $link ):
                                $link_url = $link['url'];
                                $link_title = $link['title'];
                                $link_target = $link['target'] ? $link['target'] : '_self';
                                ?>
                                <a class="cta-button" href="<?php echo esc_url( $link_url ); ?>" target="<?php echo esc_attr( $link_target ); ?>"><?php echo esc_html( $link_title ); ?></a>
                            <?php endif; ?>
                    </div>
                </div>
            <?php endwhile;?>
        <div class="pagination">
            <?php
            
                $big = 999999999; // need an unlikely integer
                echo paginate_links( array(
                    'base'      => str_replace( $big, '%#%', esc_url( get_pagenum_link( $big ) ) ),
                    'format'    => '?paged=%#%',
                    'current' => max( 1, get_query_var('paged') ),
                    'total'     => $the_query->max_num_pages,
                ) );
            ?>
        </div>
   
        
        </div>
    <?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
    <?php
    return ob_get_clean();
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
$args = array (
    'post_type'     => 'ebooks-guides',
    'posts_per_page' => 4,
    'orderby'=> 'title',
    'order' => 'ASC',
    'paged' => get_query_var('paged'),

);
```

Comment: Unfortunately, still not working on my end after clicking the pagination it still going to homepage.

Answer (score 0):

Add below function in your function.php file

```
//  Pagination function
function pagination_bar( $custom_query ) {

    $total_pages = $custom_query->max_num_pages;
    $big = 999999999; // need an unlikely integer

    if ($total_pages > 1){
        $current_page = max(1, get_query_var('paged'));

        echo paginate_links(array(
            'base' => str_replace( $big, '%#%', esc_url( get_pagenum_link( $big ) ) ),
            'format' => '?paged=%#%',
            'current' => $current_page,
            'total' => $total_pages,
        ));
    }
}
```

And add below code in your view area after loop complete.

```
echo pagination_bar( $the_query);
```